# Should replacement GCFI receptacle match the one being replaced or the breaker rating?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Recently moved into a home and am doing a bathroom reno.  The old GFCI receptacle (20a) currently installed must be replaced however the circuit breaker for that room says 15?  Should I change receptacle to 15 or replace like for like?  There will be a fan, 2 pot lights and an overhead vanity light (3 lights).

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be replaced?  "Tripping a lot" is very similar to "My radon alarm is constantly beeping" - it has one job, and it may be, y'know, *doing it*. Even if that is inconvenient.

Comment: If you are "renovating the bathroom" you will probably have to bring the bathroom electrics up to code, so you'll need to run 12 AWG wire to support a 20A circuitfor the countertop not shared with anything other than *possibly* another bathroom. You could put the lights and fan on the 15A circuit you have now.

Comment: lets give you some points so can actually comment

Comment: @Ecnerwal - if supplying a single bathroom, the 20A circuit can supply additional outlets in that bathroom. Or, that is my reading of 210.11(C)(3), specifically the Exception.

Comment: Yes, it could do lights and fan, but unless the current 15A wire is actually 12 AWG everywhere, or terrifying falling apart fabric-insulated stuff pushing or well past 70 years old, might as well use that circuit for those. The 20A circuit can feed every outlet in the bathroom, or two bathrooms, and the lights, etc in the bathroom, but can't serve loads not in the bathroom. The lights, fan, etc. can be on a circuit that serves loads outside the bathroom. The rule is MOSTLY about hairdryers, etc. IMHO.

Comment: @Ruskes You can always comment on your own posts, btw

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms you can always upvote newcomers

Answer (score 10):

**15A**

You can put 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit. But you can't put 20A receptacles on a 15A circuit.

Either someone else messed up, or the circuit was 20A and was extended with 14 AWG wire which forced a downgrade to 15A and didn't realize there was a 20A receptacle in the circuit.

A few other important things to note:

- Bathroom Receptacle Requirements

Bathrooms are supposed to have at least one 20A circuit feeding bathroom receptacles. That can be shared with receptacles in other bathrooms or lights/fan/etc. in this bathroom. Technically nothing else. In reality plenty of older houses (built under older code) have (a) 15A instead of 20A, (b) circuits shared with receptacles and/or lighting in other rooms.

A renovation - tear down to the studs - will normally requiring bringing electrical (and plumbing) up to the current code. But there are renovations and there are renovations. Painting only? No. Painting and tile? No. Replace a toilet with a similar (but lower water usage) one? No. Etc. Do all these things at once and it becomes a non-grandfathering renovation. So you need to consider the situation and possibly check with your local building department to find out whether you can stay with the 15A circuit or not.

That being said, the *immediate* fix is to put in a 15A receptacle. That makes things *safe*, and it is also compatible with later switching to a 20A circuit should that be necessary. But don't change the breaker to 20A unless you have made 100% certain that all wire in the circuit - including any extensions to other bathrooms or other rooms - is 12 AWG and none of it is 14 AWG.

- Line vs. Load

GFCI can protect anything from a single receptacle to an entire circuit. A *typical* installation is a GFCI/receptacle that also protects other stuff via the **LOAD** terminals. While that is a very good idea for additional receptacles, it may not be such a good idea for lights. In general, lights and fans in a bathroom do *not* need to be GFCI-protected unless they are in wet areas - i.e., above a tub or shower. If not required, it is actually a good idea to *not* GFCI protect lights as a GFCI trip due to a problem with a hair dryer or other appliance would leave you in the dark. Wiring up a GFCI to properly handle line and load can be confusing, but is pretty easy once you understand the basics.

- Nuisance Trips vs. Real Trips

A GFCI never *needs* to be replaced unless it is physically damaged or it fails to pass the TEST/RESET cycle or an internal self-test process. If a GFCI seems to trip a lot, don't jump to replace it. The problem may actually be an actual *ground fault*! Imagine that! Those are not nuisance trips, they are real trips. For example, a while back I found out from my family that a nightlight in a bathroom would trip the GFCI if they touched it when their hands were damp. They thought maybe there was something wrong with the GFCI/receptacle. I told them "*no, that's the GFCI doing its job*". They said "how about if we use the nightlight elsewhere?" I said "*no, it is defective, replace it with another nightlight*", and of course that solved the problem.

Comment: And isn't it required that a bathroom have a dedicated 20 A circuit going to it?

Comment: Thanks manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact.  The previous owner might have messed up....breaker box says 15 on it for bathroom (and tested it too - when off everything is off) - don't think it can be wrong?  Will a 15a GFCI receptacle support fan, pot lights and vanity lights?

Comment: Not sure Stevesh....someone put it in lol

Comment: As long as there is no heater a 15A circuit can handle all that. Yes should be 20A but old are grandfathered and 15A safe is better than 20A unsafe.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I read *"bathroom reno"* as doing enough work that grandfather goes in the dumpster and you have to have the 20A circuit for the worktop.

Comment: @Ecnerwal First of all, when I read your comment I had visions of an old guy going dumpster diving...until I realized what you meant! Second of all, I didn't notice "reno" originally.

Comment: I have had to replace a GFCI because it tripped if you looked at it funny. It was many years old. The replacement works just fine with the same devices. So it's not a 'never' thing maybe so much as a 'rarely' thing that GFCIs can be problematic in that way.

Comment: In the last 25 years as a homeowner I've encountered 2 different GFCIs that started tripping constantly. After checking for sources of ground faults, I replaced the GFCI outlet and the problem was solved. In one case I wired up the outlet in a box and tested it, and it tripped with no loads at all connected. That proved to me that the GFCI was faulty. They DO fail.

Comment: I've also had a couple of cases where the GFCI was tripping and it turned out to be a legit ground fault. One such case was "monument lights" at the end of my driveway. When we bought the house, about 10,000 outlets were slaved off of a single GFCI in the master bathroom, including the monument lights, all the 2nd level bathroom outlets, and the garage outlets.) The buried wires to the monument lights would get damp in heavy rain, tripping the GFCI.

Comment: That caused our sprinkler system, FIOS phone/internet, and various other important things to die. I did a big rewire to isolate the monument lights, and added 3 or 4 new GFCIs to protect the other parts of the circuit separately. Now when it rains the monument lights will go out, but our phone doesn't die any more.